# to overload a data type or to use a similar one?

Tags: haskell

This is more of a question about a programming style and common practices. But I feel that it does not fit into the code review forum...

My program parses regular expressions and processes them. A regular expression can have the usual elements (Kleene closure, concatenation, etc) and it also can have references to other regular expressions by their names, like macros:

```
data Regex a = Epsilon
             | Literal a
             | Ranges [(a, a)]
             | Ref String
             | Then (Regex a) (Regex a)
             | Or (Regex a) (Regex a)
             | Star (Regex a)
```

After I process a regular expression and resolve all macro references, and convert `Literal` elements to `Range` elements (this is needed for my purposes), I end up with a type that cannot and must not have `Ref` and `Literal`, so in my functions that work with it I do something like:

```
foo (Literal _) = error "unexpected literal"
foo (Ref _)     = error "unexpected reference"
foo (Epsilon)   = ...
foo (Star x)    = ...
...
```

This looks ugly to me because it does runtime checks instead of checks during compilation. Not a very haskell kind of approach.

So maybe I can introduce another data type which is very similar to the original one and use that?

```
data RegexSimple a = Epsilon2
                   | Ranges2 [(a, a)]
                   | Then2 (Regex a) (Regex a)
                   | Or2 (Regex a) (Regex a)
                   | Star2 (Regex a)
```

That would work, but here I have a lot of duplication and also the nice and descriptive names of constructors are taken now and I need to invent new ones...

What would the experts do here? I want to learn : )

Comment: Have you looked at [GADTs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT)?

Comment: Just want to point out that you can use a second data type with the "same" constructor names if you define it in a different module. Then you can use `import qualified ... as ...` if some code needs to deal with both types.

Comment: Also take a look at `Data Types A La Carte` http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, so this solution may require you to rethink certain aspects, but the most "haskell-ish" solution to this problem would probably be to use [GADTs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) and [phantom types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Phantom_types). Together, they basically allow you to create arbitrary subtypes for more flexible type safety. You would redefine your types like so.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Literal
data Ref
data Rangeable

data Regex t a where
         Epsilon :: Regex Rangeable a
         Literal :: a -> Regex Literal a
         Ranges  :: [(a, a)] -> Regex Rangeable a
         Ref     :: String -> Regex Ref a
         Then    :: Regex t' a -> Regex t' a -> Regex Rangeable a
         Or      :: Regex t' a -> Regex t' a -> Regex Rangeable a
         Star    :: Regex t' a -> Regex Rangeable
```

Then you can define

```
foo :: Regex Rangeable a
foo (Epsilon)  = ...
foo s@(Star a) = ...
```

Now, statements like `foo $ Literal 'c'` will fail compile-time type-checks.

Comment: That's great. I've never seen this technique before. Is there any resource about it ?

Comment: Take a look at the links I included in my answer ([this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT))

Comment: @Kwarrtz thanks this works although I had to change the types of my `Then`, `Or`, `Star`, `Epsilon` to the general case: `Regex t' a -> Regex t' a -> Regex t' a`, etc. Because I need them in all sub-types.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I forget to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert but it's a problem I have also myself (even though it more with product type than sum type).

The obvious solution is to reuse `RegexSimple` in `Regex` so that

```
 data Regex a = Ref a | Literal a | SimpleR (SimpleRegex a)
```

another way is to parametrize Regex with a functor

```
data Regex f a = Literal (f a) | Ref (f a) | Epsilon a ...
```

and use either `Regex Id` or `Regex Void`.

Another way is just to use `Maybe`

```
data Regex a = Literal (Maybe a) | Epsilon a ...
```

But this it less clean because you can't enforce a function to only accept simple regex.